# Azure AD conditional access policy for cloud app not applying

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that authenticates on our AzureAD, this works fine. Now I have created a conditional access policy following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa#configure-the-conditions-for-multi-factor-authentication) where I have:

- Applied the policy to all users
- Linked the app registration for my app under Cloud Apps
- Grant Access enabled
- Require MFA is enabled
- Policy is enabled

However when logging in to my app, even after hours of waiting for any change to pass through, I never get prompted for MFA. The account I use to authenticate does get prompted for MFA when I log in to the Azure Portal, our webmail, VPN, etc.

The login URL is structured as follows:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={appRegistrationId}&redirect_uri={appUrl}%2fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid+profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce]&domain_hint=example.com&state={state}&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0&sso_nonce={ssoNonce}&client-request-id={requestId}&mscrid={mscrid}
```

Hopefully someone can help me figure out why I'm not getting an MFA challenge.

Comment: If you use account that is already signed-in in the same browser using MFA, nothing fancy will happen when navigating to your app. Because your browser already has an active MFA SSO session with the browser. Do you observe same behavior if you try to login to your application in an `incognito / guest / private` browser session?

Comment: That's it! I didn't think of the SSO scenario because I do get prompted for MFA every time I open the Azure Portal. But this was exactly it. Thanks!